# C++ capture screen using DirectX11

Tags: c++, windows, directx-11, dxgi

I am trying to use DirectX11 in C++ to Capture the screen and convert it to a texture I can render with OpenGL or ImGui. I have used the Windows API with BitBlt, this however results in fps lower than 15, so this is not an option.

I am using Windows 11, with a Nvidia graphics card.

Library Import:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "dxgi.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "d3d11.lib")
```

Initializing DirectX11:

```
    bool DirectX11::initDirectX11() {
        HRESULT hr = S_OK;
        IDXGIFactory* DXGIFactory = nullptr;
        IDXGIAdapter* Adapter = nullptr;
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL FeatureLevel = D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0;
        Output = nullptr;
        deskDupl = nullptr;


        hr = CreateDXGIFactory(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory), (void**)(&DXGIFactory));
        if (FAILED(hr)) {
            std::cout << "Failed to create DXGI Factory" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }


        hr = DXGIFactory->EnumAdapters(0, &Adapter);
        if (FAILED(hr)) {
            std::cout << "Failed to create adapter" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }


        hr = Adapter->EnumOutputs(0, &Output);
        if (FAILED(hr)) {
            std::cout << "Failed to create output" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }

        hr = Output->QueryInterface(__uuidof(Output), (void**)(&deskDupl));
        if (FAILED(hr)) {
            std::cout << "Failed to create output1" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }


        hr = Output->GetDesc(&OutputDesc);
        if (FAILED(hr)) {
            std::cout << "Failed to get output description" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }

        hr = D3D11CreateDevice(Adapter, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_UNKNOWN, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &device, &FeatureLevel, &deviceContext);
        if (FAILED(hr)) {
            std::cout << "Failed to create D3D11 device" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }

        DXGIFactory->Release();
        Adapter->Release();
        return true;
    }
```

Capturing the Screen:

```
    void  DirectX11::captureScreen() {
        HRESULT hr = S_OK;

        IDXGIResource* DesktopResource;
        DXGI_OUTDUPL_FRAME_INFO FrameInfo;

        // Get new frame
        hr = deskDupl->AcquireNextFrame(500, &FrameInfo, &DesktopResource);
        if (FAILED(hr)) {
            std::cout << "Failed to acquire next frame" << std::endl;
            return;
        }

        
        // Store the frame as a texture
        // Trows exception
        // Read access violation
        // DesktopResource was 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF   
        hr = DesktopResource->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&AcquiredDesktopImage));
        if (FAILED(hr)) {
            std::cout << "Failed to query interface" << std::endl;
            return;
        }

    }
```

The problem is that it keeps throwing a read acces violation exception.

```
Read access violation
DesktopResource was 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

Comment: It seems very unlikely that you get a pointer value set to 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF calling AcquireNextFrame with a valid HRESULT returned. I suspect the code you show in your question is not exactly the code you run. You can have a look at the official sample https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/main/Samples/DXGIDesktopDuplication or post a reproducible project [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: AcquiredDesktopImage is never initialized, and using the Visual Studio debugger I can see that the value stays NULL. However it does show that altough AcquiredDesktopImage is NULL, there is still a ID3D11Resource  under AcquiredDesktopImage which has as value <struct at NULL>. Please keep in mind that AcquiredDesktopImage is a pointer to a ID3D11texture2D

Comment: I'm not talking about `AcquiredDesktopImage`, I'm talking about `DesktopResource`. You say the value of `DesktopResource` is `0x0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` which is not possible if `AcquireNextFrame` call returned a successful HRESULT.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. `desktopRescource` is first `0xcccccccccccccccc` and after `AcquirenextFrame`it is `0xcccccccc00000000`. Which would be normal. However when I use the Visual Studi debugger it shows that `desktopRescource` Contains some subobjects, but unlike `FrameInfo` I cannot see what the value is of `desktopRescource`.  is. The subjects are all nested, and ending in `_vfptr: <Unable to read memory> `

Comment: DesktopResource cannot be set to 0xcccccccc00000000 if resulting HESULT is successful (ie: `SUCCEEDED(hr)` or `!FAILED(hr)` are true). This would *not be normal*. Or you have other serious low level issues (process corruption, buffer overrun, multithreading issues, etc.). Provide a reproducible sample.

Comment: I have made a github repository that can be used to recreate the issue. It is using the gdb debugger with visual studio code so you might need to change the paths voor the debugger. Or `premake5 vs2022` to create a visual studio project. [directx11testing](https://github.com/timvnaarden/directx11testing)

Comment: `Output->QueryInterface(__uuidof(Output), (void**)(&deskDupl));` is wrong, the IID parameter must be IID_IDXGIOutputDuplication

Comment: Changing this sadly makes no difference

Comment: Indeeed, your output is `IDXGIOutput`, not `IDXGIOutput1`, so you must do `Output->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIOutput1), (void**)(&o1));`first and then `o1->DuplicateOutput(device, &deskDupl);` but for the later to succeed, you must replace `CreateDXGIFactory` by `CreateDXGIFactory1`

Comment: Thank you, everything works as expected now. Kind of sad that is cost me an entire day for something this simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code

```
hr = Output->QueryInterface(__uuidof(Output), (void**)(&deskDupl));
```

Is invalid as it writes an `IDXGIOutput` reference to an `IDXGIOutputDuplication` reference.

To get an `IDXGIOutputDuplication` reference, you must call the [IDXGIOutput1::DuplicateOutput method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi1_2/nf-dxgi1_2-idxgioutput1-duplicateoutput), so you must get an `IDXGIOutput1` first, like this:

```
IDXGIOutput1* o1;
hr = Output->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIOutput1), (void**)(&o1));
```

And then

```
hr = o1->DuplicateOutput(device, &deskDupl);
```

But for this to succeed, you must create the device from an `IDXGIFactory1` or from an `IDXGIFactory` factory created from [CreateDXGIFactory1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi/nf-dxgi-createdxgifactory1) (DXGI 1.1), so replace the call `CreateDXGIFactory` by `CreateDXGIFactory1`.

Note: to avoid casting to dangerous `(void**)` for `QueryInterface` and many other COM calls, and so avoid raw casting errors (some of it at least) when working with Visual Studio you can use the [IID_PPV_ARGS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-iid_ppv_args) macro. So you can write this:

```
hr = Output->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&o1));
```

And nowadays, `IUnknown` defining headers (Windows SDK's `Unknwnbase.h`) also defines some more useful C++ templates, so you can even call QueryInterface like this directly:

```
hr = Output->QueryInterface(&o1);
```

PS: note sure this exists with other compilers than MSVC.